# How to break out of a for loop started on click of a button from another button

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I started execution of a `for-loop` on click of a button. Now I want that when another button is clicked then execution of the `for-loop` that i started earlier should stop and I want to retrieve the value of counter when this `for-loop` stops executing. How can I achieve this?

```
public void clickStart(View view) {
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<1500;i++) {
            counter = counter + 10;
            textView.setText(counter);
        }
    }

public void clickComplete(View view) {
    //Write code to stop executing for loop in clickStart()
}
```

Comment: try using Thread(Runnable/Handler)

Comment: Won't the execution be long over when the user clicks the button ?.. the cpu will swallow it with ease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this isn't exactly the answer for how to stop a `for-loop` from outside (for which you already have received answers from other users), but after looking at your question it seems you are trying to show a counter that increments in 10s in your textview with some delay for which you are using the `for-loop`.

I would like to point out that your `for-loop` will finish executing within some milliseconds, i.e. as soon as you click the button to start the loop your textview will show the final value of counter which is `15000` in your case.

If my assumption was right about the delay you need you can make use of handler and implement is as shown below:

First declare these as global variables in your activity or fragment where you will be using it.

```
TextView textView;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable;
int counter;  //for the +10 counter you were originally using
int count;    //for number of times to execute
```

Textview needs to be called from multiple methods hence, the global usage.

Now in the `onCreate()` method you can write the following code:

```
textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (count <= 1500) {
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            count++;
            counter += 10;
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
          //500 milliseconds for half a second delay change this as you require
        } else {
            handler.removeCallbacks(this);
        }
    }
};
```

Inside the `run()` method is the code that determines what is to be executed after the mentioned delay.

Now assuming you know how to use onClickListeners on your buttons, your `startClick` method should look like this:

```
public void startClick(View v) {
        counter = 0;
        count = 0;
        handler.post(runnable);
    }
```

so every time you click start counter will reset to 0, if you don't want it to reset initialize values outside the start function in `onCreate` before the runnable. Finally, the `clickComplete` method should be to simply stop the runnable as below:

```
public void clickComplete(View v) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
```

Let me know if this was of any help to you.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. All the for loop answers are simply stupid.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this

```
public boolean stopExecution = false;
public int counter = 0;

public void clickStart(View view) {
       TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        counter = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<1500;i++) {
            counter = counter + 10;
            textView.setText(counter);
            // also here use String.valueOf(counter) this would throw sn error in my android studio

            if(stopExecution){
                  stopExecution = false;
                  break;
             }
        }
}

public void clickComplete(View view) {
       stopExecution = true;

       // you can access the "global" value counter from here at whatever value it stopped
       // in case it is still running it will break the execution and you will have the vslue where it stopped
       // but the processor should handle it very fast so maybe you need some delayed loop or ?
)
```

Answer (score 0):

On way is to add a method in your code:

```
public boolean isRunning()
        {
            return this.keepRunning;
        }
```

And in your code do this:

```
public void clickStart(View view) {
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<1500;i++) {
            counter = counter + 10;
            textView.setText(counter);
            if(isRunning){
            keepRunning=false;
            break;
            }
        }
    }

public void clickComplete(View view) {
    //Write code to stop executing for loop in clickStart()
      this.keepRunning=true;

}
```

2nd way is to use handler thread:

Instead of using a for loop, you can let the Runnable instance call itself for a specific number of times. These calls will be posted to UI thread queue so, keep that in mind.

The following code should do it:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
int count = 0;

final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { 
        // need to do tasks on the UI thread 
        Log.d(TAG, "Run test count: " + count);
        if (yourcondition) {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }
    } 
}; 

// trigger first time 
handler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: can you explain the handler way in more detail? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have added handler's details

Comment: thanks but my issue got resolved by trying the accepted solution